# Find validation algorythm

Tags: python, machine-learning, math

Sorry for my amateur question but i don't know how to start searching about this.
So i have a dataset with numbers and the result (its valid or it isn't) and i think it has something to do with check digit for error detection (like an isbn) but i am not sure, the dataset look's something like this:

```
1000369876  1
1000369877  0
1000369878  0
1000369879  0
1000369880  0
1000369881  0
1000369882  0
1000369883  0
1000369884  1
1000369885  0
1000369886  0
1000369887  0
1000369888  0
1000369889  0
1000369890  0
1000369891  0
1000369892  1
1000369893  0
1000369894  0
...
```

it would help even having a method that just validates future ones.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any context for where the data came from? It's not ISBN.

Comment: Yeah i know that why i wrote "like an ISBN". Its about a project for crawling where some ID exist and some don't and no one are deleted its just the way the are generated. But i don't see how that would help here. Thanks

Comment: Without more details, I don't really know what you're looking for. Would you be satisfied with an explanation of how ISBN codes work, so you could write something that would check different possible ecc vectors?

Comment: Maybe training a machine-learing model that checks if a Number/ID is valid based on my dataset, i tried searching about that but it seems hard to find anything related

Comment: You can only train a model like that if you know what pattern you're looking for. Models are for statistical predictions on continuous variables, not for algorithmic validation tasks.

Comment: Okay so its seems thats not the way to go, thanks.
I will leave the question open if someone knows something for a few days

Comment: your question and requirements lacks details. You need to more details about your dataset and what is your requirement from that

Comment: Upon further inspection, the numbers are all sequential and every 8th is valid. I just posted an answer explaining as much, it would be greatly appreciated if you mark it as accepted and we can both be on our way :)

Comment: @LionelFoxcroft sorry for that but people like him make Stackoverflow a place where people are scared to ask. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that data is representative of the rest, you can test it by doing this:

```py
def valid(n):
    return n % 8 == 4
```